# How can I loop this script that assigns values to variables?

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm looking to loop the following script, as to save lines of code, and manual hardcoding. The script pulls specific values from my database and assigns them to variables that are used across my website.

```
    $w1001a = $conn->query("SELECT columnB FROM table WHERE columnA='w1001a' limit 1")->fetch_object()->content; 
    $w1001b = $conn->query("SELECT columnB FROM table WHERE columnA='w1001b' limit 1")->fetch_object()->content; 
    ....
    $w1025b = $conn->query("SELECT columnB FROM table WHERE columnA='w1001b' limit 1")->fetch_object()->content;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you need to use a IN statement or use a regex for `columnA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't loop the query, use one query to get all the info.

***The below is just dummy code:***

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT columnA, columnB FROM table WHERE columnA IN ('w1001a', 'w1001b', ...)");
$result = array();
while ($obj = $stmt->fetch_object()) {
  $result[$obj->columnA] = $obj->columnB;
}
```

Comment: The query might need a first/one-in-group (i.e. to cover the limit 1), but this is generally a much better approach ..

Comment: Thanks @xdazz - Now the data is accessible through $result[w1001a], rather than $w1001a. How would I finish this last step?